# Dropdown list with links and validation

Tags: validation, dropdown

I am creating a drop down list that will send you to another site.  When a site is selected, it doesn't send the user to the correct site.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<div id="selection">
    <form name="division_form" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" action="global_complaint_training.php?page=1">
        <select name="division_list">
            <option selected disabled>Select a Language:</option>
            <option value="1">english</option>
            <option value="2">español</option>
            <option value="3">français</option>
        </select>
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>


function validateForm(formElement) {
    var x = formElement.division_list.selectedIndex;
    if (x == 0) {
        alert('Please choose a language');
        return false;
    } else {
        switch(x) {
            case 1:
                document.division_form.action = "english/training.php?page=1";
                break;
            case 2:
                document.division_form.action = "spanish/training.php?page=1";
                break;
            case 3:
                document.division_form.action = "french/training.php?page=1";
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When a site is selected this is included in the site: division_list=5&Submit=Submit and page=1 is not included in the site.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must decide what you want to do. You can redirect the user to another site uses js or PHP. If you want to use PHP, a form should send variables to PHP document and there should be code which redirects the user. If you want to use js, you should just use:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

in a switch statement.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's going to the site but it adds submit at the end of the website: www.training.php?division_list=1&Submit=Submit

Comment: It's that because you are using get method in your form. If you don't want to have variables in URL, you should use POST method. I would be glad if you added plus to mine answer.

Answer (score 0):

Include the action attribute with it set to "post"

```html
  <form name="division_form" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" action="global_complaint_training.php?page=1">
```

**Should be**

```html
    <form name="division_form" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" action="global_complaint_training.php?page=1" method="post">
```